# What command can raise error in bash script?

Tags: python, macos, gunicorn, supervisord

I check status in supervisor by next command:

```
sudo supervisorctl -c /usr/local/etc/supervisord.ini status
```

The command below return me in terminal next message:

```
beta FATAL command at '/Users/username/Projects/bash_scripts/beta.sh' is not executable
```

`beta` is a name of the project.

**supervisord.ini**:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/usr/local/var/run/supervisor.sock

[supervisord]
logfile=/usr/local/var/log/supervisord.log
logfile_maxbytes=50MB
logfile_backups=10
loglevel=info
pidfile=/usr/local/var/run/supervisord.pid
nodaemon=false
minfds=1024
minprocs=200

; The betainterface:supervisor section must remain in the config file for
; BETA (supervisorctl/web interface) to work.  Additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate [betainterface:x] sections.

[betainterface:supervisor]
supervisor.betainterface_factory = supervisor.betainterface:make_main_betainterface

[supervisorctl]
serverurl=unix:///usr/local/var/run/supervisor.sock

[include]
files = /usr/local/etc/supervisor.d/*.ini
```

Inside  `/usr/local/etc/supervisor.d/` folder I have **beta.ini** file which has next code:

```
[program:beta]
directory = /Applications/Projects/web/beta
user = nurzhan
command = /Applications/Projects/bash_scripts/beta.sh
stderr_logfile = /Applications/Projects/logs/supervisor-beta.log
stdout_logfile = /Applications/Projects/logs/supervisor-beta.log
```

**beta.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /Applications/Projects/web/beta
export TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/instantclient_11_2
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/Virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages'
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/bin/python2.7
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14/bin/virtualenv
export PIP_VIRTUALENV_BASE=$WORKON_HOME
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh 
workon beta
exec gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:8009 -w 4 --user=nurzhan --log-level=INFO --log-file=/Applications/Projects/logs/gunicorn-beta.log wsgi:app
```

I check my `beta.sh` file several times but steal don't understand what command can be wrong. What can you advice?

Comment: Can you paste each line individually into your shell? That should clear-up which is the culprit.

Comment: `bash -x yourscript` will log each command as it runs; in this case, `command = /usr/bin/env bash /Applications/Projects/bash_scripts/beta.sh` might be appropriate. Much more reliable than depending on an interactive shell to behave similarly to a noninteractive one. (That said, as an aside -- using `.sh` extensions for executable bash scripts is poor form: A `.sh` extension implies compatibility with POSIX sh, and UNIX commands don't typically have extensions at all).

Comment: @chrisaycock I executed each command separately in terminal. On the last command the terminal freezes, but there are no error messages. So I am little bit confused. Do you have any ideas my friend?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for information. I tried `bash -x beta.sh` command. It don't raise any error (minus). All lines has plus symbols. So I am really confused.

Comment: Also I notice that `gunicorn-beta.log` has logs, which mean that last command in beta.sh file works, right?

Comment: Guys also I notice that when I first time check supervisor status after reload it, I see `BACKOFF` message. When I check status again I see `FATAL`.

Comment: Did you run `command = /usr/bin/env bash -x /Applications/Projects/bash_scripts/beta.sh`? If so, it'll log everything the bash script is doing. If it does everything you expect, we can be certain this isn't a bash problem.

Comment: ...as for "is not executable", though -- did you run `chmod +x` to give your script execute permission?